# How to change image source of html element using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I've been searching the internet for someone who is having the same problem but I wasn't able to find a solution. I just can't figure out how to change the source of an image using javascript. I initially thought that it might be because I was writing the javascript in another file instead of within the actual html file but I tried putting the script within the html file and that didn't work either. If someone could tell me if there's something I'm doing wrong that would be great.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      Rock Paper Scissors Game
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <body>
      <header>
        <h1>Rock Paper Scissors</h1>
      </header>
      <div class="score-board">
        <div id="user-label" class="badge">user</div>
        <div id="computer-label" class="badge">comp</div>
        <span id="user-score">0</span>:<span id="computer-score">0</span>
      </div>
      <div class="result">
        <p>Make Your Move!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="choices">
        <div class="choice" **onclick="changeImg()**" id="r">
          <img src="images/rock.png" width="115" height="95" />
        </div>
        <div class="choice" id="p">
          <img src="images/paper.png" width="120" height="120" />
        </div>
        <div class="choice" id="s">
          <img src="images/scissors.png" width="130" height="110" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="fighters">
        <div class="fighter" id="u">
          <img src="images/rock.png" width="370" height="300" />
        </div>
        <div class="fighter" id="c">
          <img src="images/rockflipped.png" width="370" height="300" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="squares">
        <div class="square" id="userSquare"></div>
        <div class="square" id="computerSquare"></div>
      </div>

      **
      <script>
        var userImg = document.getElementById('u');
        var compImg = document.getElementById('c');
        function changeImg() {
          console.log('here');
          userImg.src = '‪file:///C:/...scissors.png';
        }
      </script>
      **

      <script src="app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </body>
  </head>
</html>
```

Comment: userImg.attr('src', '‪file:///C:/...scissors.png')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Simple Description

You need to put the `id` attribute inside the `img` tag. 
And it needs to be unique. What you are doing now is that you are getting the `div` which is not the actual image.

**Example:**

```
      <img var userImg = document.getElementById("c500");

<script>

                function changeImg()
                {
                    console.log("here");
                    userImg.src = "https://i.chzbgr.com/full/8759954176/hFD7BD608/can-has-code-review.jpg";
                }

                changeImg(); 

</script>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m56tq1ba/

### Full Source

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
<title>
  Rock Paper Scissors Game
</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Rock Paper Scissors</h1>
  </header>
  <div class="score-board">
    <div id="user-label" class="badge">user</div>
    <div id="computer-label" class="badge">comp</div>
    <span id="user-score">0</span>:<span id="computer-score">0</span>
  </div>
  <div class="result">
    <p>Make Your Move!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="choices">
    <div class="choice" onclick="changeImg()" id="r">
      <img src="images/rock.png" width="115" height="95" />
    </div>
    <div class="choice" id="p">
      <img src="images/paper.png" width="120" height="120" />
    </div>
    <div class="choice" id="s">
      <img src="images/scissors.png" width="130" height="110" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="fighters">
    <div class="fighter" id="u">
      <img id="userImg_100" src="images/rock.png" width="370" height="300" />
    </div>
    <div class="fighter" id="c">
      <img src="images/rockflipped.png" width="370" height="300" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="squares">
    <div class="square" id="userSquare"></div>
    <div class="square" id="computerSquare"></div>
  </div>

  <script>
    var userImg = document.getElementById('userImg_100');
    var compImg = document.getElementById('c');
    function changeImg() {
      console.log('here');
      userImg.src = '‪https://i.chzbgr.com/full/8759954176/hFD7BD608/can-has-code-review.jpg';
    }
  </script>


  <script src="app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
  </head>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, sorry I'm really new to web design.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is you are getting the div with the id="u" and assigning the src for that which wont work.
Get the `image` by assigning an id to it and ge that image tag by its id and assign the image. modified your code little bit as below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      Rock Paper Scissors Game
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <body>
      <header>
        <h1>Rock Paper Scissors</h1>
      </header>
      <div class="score-board">
        <div id="user-label" class="badge">user</div>
        <div id="computer-label" class="badge">comp</div>
        <span id="user-score">0</span>:<span id="computer-score">0</span>
      </div>
      <div class="result">
        <p>Make Your Move!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="choices">
        <div class="choice" **onclick="changeImg()**" id="r">
          <img src="images/rock.png" width="115" height="95" />
        </div>
        <div class="choice" id="p">
          <img src="images/paper.png" width="120" height="120" />
        </div>
        <div class="choice" id="s">
          <img src="images/scissors.png" width="130" height="110" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="fighters">
        <div class="fighter" id="u">
          <img id="u_image" src="images/rock.png" width="370" height="300" />
        </div>
        <div class="fighter" id="c">
          <img id="c_image" src="images/rockflipped.png" width="370" height="300" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="squares">
        <div class="square" id="userSquare"></div>
        <div class="square" id="computerSquare"></div>
      </div>

      **
      <script>
        var userImg = document.getElementById('u_image');
        var compImg = document.getElementById('c_image');
        function changeImg() {
          console.log('here');
          userImg.src = '‪file:///C:/...scissors.png';
        }
      </script>
      **

      <script src="app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </body>
  </head>
</html>
```